# merge progress bar with transport (copy or move) codes in colab

Tags: python, list, python-requests, torrent, libtorrent

can you tell me,how can i solve this runtime error?
i have a move file code in colab :

```
import shutil
import os
source_path="/content/colab_torrent_download/"
destination_path = "/content/mega/"
files = os.listdir(source_path)
for file in files:
   shutil.move(os.path.join(source_path,file), destination_path)
```

that works correct.
now i have another code for progress bar:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
result = 0
for i in tqdm(range(10000000)):
    result += i
```

now i want to add my progress bar code to move code.
who can help me ? pls write final combined code for me ... i didn't work with python yet.tnx alot.

Comment: `for file in tqdm(files):` ?

Comment: for moving files in upper code , i need a progress bar that shows progress percent.

Comment: Have you tried my proposition in comment ?